# Can people sell Ubuntu on Ebay?

Tags: legal

Tired of windows and was told by a workmate about Ubuntu. Sounds promising! I ran across a couple of Ebay sellers that are selling Ubuntu. I thought that was prohibited?

Do you think that this is a fake Ubuntu with viruses?

Answer (score 5):

Why would that be prohibited? You are free to sell Ubuntu as much as you like. It's free software, after all. I don't really understand why you would want to buy it from a third-party, though. But it's perfectly legal. You can purchase official CDs from http://shop.ubuntu.com if you want to.

It's impossible to tell whether it's the official version they're selling or not, and if not, what they've done to it. However, if they claim that it is the official version, it's extremely easy to check. You'll just check the contents against the md5 sums available from official channels.

If you have an ok internet connection, I would rather just download it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is free software mainly under GPL license; so everyone's free to sell if they want to. But Ubuntu name and logo are registered trademarks of Canonical Ltd. (look at the footer of this page!) so Canonical could take action if they want to.